# Merge Pandas dataframe to a list of dataframes, excluding rows from the merge that matched successfully to a prevoius table in the list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a master dataframe with the columns ['UniqueID','Col1','Col2]

I also have a list of dataframes `[Table1,Table2,Table3]`, each of the dataframes in the list contains only the same 2 columns: `['UniqueID','JoinID']`. The JoinID column is set to be the value of the table, so that once they are merged back to the master dataframe, I will know which table they joined from. For Example:

```
masterDF = {'UniqueID': ['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6'],'Col1':['a','b','c','d','e','f'],'Col2':['a','b','c','d','e','f']}

table1 = {'UniqueID': ['A1','A2','A3'],'JoinID': ['Table1', 'Table1','Table1'] }
table2 = {'UniqueID': ['A1','A3','A4'],'JoinID': ['Table2', 'Table2','Table2'] }
table3 = {'UniqueID': ['A3','A4','A5'],'JoinID': ['Table3', 'Table3','Table3']}
```

What I would like to do is iterate through the list in the specific order and join the masterDF to each of the tables, however, if a row had previously matched to a table in the list to not include that in the join. For example, the desired output of the merge would be:

```
    for table in tables:
        (merge each table, omitting rows which have already joined to a previous table)
    output = {'UniqueID': ['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6'], 'Col1':['a','b','c','d','e','f'], 
'Col2':['a','b','c','d','e','f'], 'JoinID':['Table1','Table1','Table1','Table2','Table3',nan]}
```

I also understand merge may not be the best joining method in that it will cause 'JoinID' column to become suffixed 'JoinID_x' and 'JoinID_y' after each join.

Is there a concise and relatively efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a `reduce` with [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stablereference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)

```
from functools import reduce

#SetUp
#master = pd.DataFrame(masterDF)
#l = [table1, table2, table3]
#l = list(map(pd.DataFrame,  l))

output = reduce(lambda cum_df, df: cum_df.combine_first(df.set_index('UniqueID')), 
                l, 
                master.set_index('UniqueID')).reset_index()
print(output)
```

**Output**

```
print(output)
  UniqueID Col1 Col2  JoinID
0       A1    a    a  Table1
1       A2    b    b  Table1
2       A3    c    c  Table1
3       A4    d    d  Table2
4       A5    e    e  Table3
5       A6    f    f     NaN
```